# What are the two arguments in revert opcode?

Tags: solidity, assembly, revert

I am trying to understand the revert opcode and how  it works . I understood that it will stop the execution of current context and return 0 to the calling context.
It seems it also takes in 2 arguments according to evm.codes. Can someone help me understand what the two arguments does?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`offset` is the starting position of the desired return data in memory and `size` is the size of the desired return data in memory. `Offset` and `size` are used to designate where the return data starts (offset) and ends (offset + size) in memory.

See: https://medium.com/@jtriley15/yul-vs-solidity-contract-comparison-2b6d9e9dc833

Comment: Thank you will check the article but I have a doubt. Why do we need to return a particular data from the memory? If it comes to revert then it is because there is some error in the smart contract and we have to return 0 only right? 

I know my question here  is bit silly but would love to understand if there are any specific cases where returning data from the memory is useful?

Comment: if there is an error, 0 is returned on the stack and the returned data is served as an error message to the caller, and doing so, it will not consume all the remaining gas. See: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-140